# Exponential coordinate notation in Open Layers GeoJson

Tags: gis, openlayers, geojson

I'm trying to draw a line using Open Layers and I sight the example here - https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/geojson.html.

```
{
   'type': 'Feature',
   'geometry': {
   'type': 'LineString',
   'coordinates': [[4e6, -2e6], [8e6, 2e6]]
 }
```

The confusion here is that how is regular lat lon coordinates converted into this exponential notation. If I use regular lat lon, nothing is drawn on the map?

```
{
   'type': 'Feature',
   'geometry': {
   'type': 'LineString',
   'coordinates': [[42.12154, -20.14515], [80.7845241, 20.4545741]]
 }
```

How do I convert my coordinates to that exponential notation?

Is there a way to draw geojson in OL using the regular coordinate system?

Answer (score 1):

These coordinates are not in lat-long but in 3857.

To use lat-long, you would need to change the Json declaration, by removing the CRS attribute

```
var geojsonObject = {
        'type': 'FeatureCollection',
        'crs': {
          'type': 'name',
          'properties': {
            'name': 'EPSG:3857'
          }
        }, ...
```

You can study this [example](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/select-features.html) and the accompanying [GeoJson](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/data/geojson/countries.geojson).

Answer (score 1):

To use latitude/longitude in your GeoJSON, you need to add the correct projections to the GeoJSON format:

```
  var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({ // VectorSource({
    features: (new ol.format.GeoJSON({
      featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857',
      dataProjection: 'EPSG:4326'})).readFeatures(geojsonObject)
  });
```

The OSM map tiles use EPSG:3857, the GeoJSON uses EPSG:4326 (which is the default).

[proof of concept](http://www.geocodezip.com/SO_OL_5.1.3_GeoJsonLatLng.html)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

**code snippet:**

```js
var styles = {
  'LineString': new ol.style.Style({
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
      color: 'green',
      width: 2
    })
  })
};

var styleFunction = function(feature) {
  return styles[feature.getGeometry().getType()];
};

var geojsonObject = {
  'type': 'FeatureCollection',
  'features': [{
    'type': 'Feature',
    'geometry': {
      'type': 'LineString',
      'coordinates': [[42.12154, -20.14515], [80.7845241, 20.4545741]]
    }
  }]
};

var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({ // VectorSource({
  features: (new ol.format.GeoJSON({
    featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857',
    dataProjection: 'EPSG:4326'
  })).readFeatures(geojsonObject)
});

var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({ // VectorLayer({
  source: vectorSource,
  style: styleFunction
});

var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({ // TileLayer({
      source: new ol.source.OSM()
    }),
    vectorLayer
  ],
  target: 'map',
  controls: ol.control.defaults({ // defaultControls({
    attributionOptions: {
      collapsible: false
    }
  }),
  view: new ol.View({
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 2
  })
});
```

```css
html,
body,
.map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://openlayers.org/en/v5.1.3/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v5.1.3/build/ol.js"></script>
<div id="map" class="map"></div>
```